# R download image from url JPEG decompression error

Tags: r, image-processing

I'm saving imaging from the website.
I see it appears and is 1.2Mb
But I fail to open it

```
download.file(
 'http://www.sothebys.com/content/dam/stb/lots/N09/N09781/101N09781_994Y9.jpg',
 method='wb', 
 destfile='~/i.jpg')
```

when I try readJPEG, I get "JPEG decompression error: Bogus marker length"

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the method 'wb' in the official documentaion. Try the 'auto' method:

```
download.file('http://www.sothebys.com/content/dam/stb/lots/N09/N09781/101N09781_994Y9.jpg',method='auto', destfile='~/i.jpg')
```

Comment: Tried all possible methods. The problem is not with the method

Comment: You may have mixed up the arguments `method` and `mode`. Take another look at the help page with   `?download.file` . Otherwise, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rohit pointed out, `method = 'auto'` works fine.

```
library(jpeg)
download.file('http://www.sothebys.com/content/dam/stb/lots/N09/N09781/101N09781_994Y9.jpg',
              method='auto', destfile='i.jpg')
x <- readJPEG("i.jpg")
```

This will return `x` as a large array.